# pip: These packages do mot match the hashes from the requirements file

Tags: python, pip

When I tried to install libraries using pip install, sometimes this error message come up.

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
```

This error comes up when I am trying to build multiple images using docker-compose V2.

What I have done:

1. `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`
2. upgrading pip
3. trying the old version of pip (20.0.2).
4. change the version of the affected package.
5. changing the dns

However, it still comes up randomly. The libraries that are referred to the error message also keep changing.

Does anyone know the reason for this issue?

Comment: What are those libraries? Are they published in pypi.org? Are they private packages? Is pypi.org proxied in some way during the installation (e.g. devpi)? Is it possible that maybe the requirements/constraints files were manually tampered but hashes were not updated alongside? Can you use the "view hashes" link in the "download files" section of the libraries in pypi.org/project/<library> to inspect what are the actual hashes of the public artifacts?

Comment: Is it possible for you to disclose the contents of the requirements.txt file?

Comment: try after step 4 `rm ~/.cache/pip -rf`

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve].

Comment: Delete in your folder "Python/PythonYOURVersion/site-packages/__pycache__" and try again

Answer (score 2):

If `--no-cache-dir` is not working for your, perhaps, you cache directory has cached packages from different requirements files. So you might want to try to delete those:

`rm ~/.cache/pip -rf` (or just specify your env .cache directory).

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same issue, tried deleting the pip cache file and using the "--no-cache-dir" argument. None of those worked.

I then came across a post that said they were experiencing this error because of a networking issue. So I switched off my VPN and everything worked perfectly!

Not sure why this works, but it got the job done

Answer (score 1):

***This is pips integrated checking mechanism that is automatically checking the integrity of the downloaded package.***

You can check yourself (by clicking view in the has column) that the sha256 of the whl file loaded from pypi should be
for example this:

```
7a2c93be4f874fd42541a1330218d2094015993420bf0bd8fbf19c88e6b49c6a
```

but for example your error says that you got this:

```
g4dd3fb13afd095a21c7dfd0d2f9bd0a3593c3c78e81ca2f475429490752e7b8
```

So `pip` is (for security reasons) not installing the package for you. I would suggest to:

- Check if `pip` is taking the `whl` from some `tmp` directory on your system with an incorrectly downloaded `whl` file sitting there - If so, try deleting it
- Check if you can install other packages without issues
- Try to manually download the `whl` file and then check the output of `pip hash <whl file>` (if it matches the `g4dd3fb13af...` sha) and if you can do `pip install <whl file>`

And besides, there was a similar problem for me, I tried it and it worked:

```
sudo pip install --no-cache-dir `YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`
```

Comment: [pip shopuld not be used blindly with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice)

Comment: I have already used --no-cache-dir, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem when installing open3d.
the --no-cache-dir method won't work.
I just used wget to download the .whl file and install it from localhost.
It's a ugly method, but really works. What you need to do is check whether the package works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it worked for me:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip YOUR-PACKAGE
```

If it doesn't work, try to get the site shown in the error and add before
"YOUR-PACKAGE" -> " --trusted-host YOUR-ERROR-SITE"
[image]

In the image above the website presented to me was

`files.pythohosted.org`

I just added
`--trusted-host files.pythohosted.org`

If still not successful, try deleting all files in `site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib`
and `site-packages/Pyinstaller/hooks`

Check if there are any files with the name of the package to be installed inside the `site-packages` folder and delete them

and try install again

Comment: Why did this get a -1?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on the required packages/libraries for the package you are trying to install. For example I tried to install jupyterlab on a windows 11 machine using pip and I got the same error. The problem were two packages "babel" and "debugpy", which I installed seperately using pip and then it worked.
The error happens probably because Python's setup was run as administrator on a local machine (I am not sure about this).
I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problems highly related to the Network settings. I tried to change my proxy and then tried for several times. Finally, it worked. Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by deleting the __pycache__ folder.

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch of any VPN connection, it worked perfectly